# What is a recommended scalable DB platform to use in AWS for large amounts of volatile data sets - elasticsearch, Redis or DynamoDB?

Tags: redis, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, autoscaling

Users of our platform will have large amounts of stored data on our system.  Through an application, once connected, that data will be transferred to them and no longer need to remain on our servers.  There could potentially be hundreds or thousands of users connected at any given time, performing their downloads.

Here's the proposed architecture:

User management, configuration, and data download statistics will be maintained in a SQL Server database, while using either Redis or DynamoDB for the large data sets.

The reason for choosing either Redis or DynamoDB is based on cost - cheaper than running another SQL Server instance, and performance.  The data format will be similar to a datamart - flat table with no joins.

Initially the queries would be simple - get all data for user X between a date range, and optionally delete.

Since we may want to add free text searching for certain fields of that data using *elasticsearch* may be a better option to use from the get-go.

I want this to be auto-scaling but not sure which database would be best to use for this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some great discussion on Database + Search tier from AWS ReInvent:

https://youtu.be/K7o5OlRLtvU?t=1574

[image: What Data Store Should I Use ?]

Answer (score 1):

I would not take Elastic-search alone because it does not provide auto-scaling for writing capacity. In fact, it's not trivial to augment the number of shard of an index. Secondly it can only handle the JSON format, which could be an issue for you.

Redis could be a good idea because it is really fast, everything is done in RAM, and it provides keys with a limited time-to-live which could be interesting for you. Unfortunately, if your data size exceeds the capacity in RAM of your amazon instance you will have to shard your Redis database. And Redis does not support it, you will have to deal it on your application code. Moreover, as far as I know Redis does not handle complex queries. You will also need to save your data in a Redis data structure which could be an issue for you

DynamoDB handles auto-scaling really well but on the other hand it is a key/value database so it does not allow you to make queries like "get all data for user X between a date range". DynamoDB also allows you to save your data in any format.

The solution will be to use either DynamoDB or either Redis depending of the size of your datas, and to use ElasticSearch in order to index your key with only the meta-data (user and dates). Like that your index will be small, and if you lost the ability to index because of ElasticSearch get too buzy, you keep the ability to save user's datas.